# Autoloader for OOP project

Tags: php, oop, autoloader

I'm currently busy with a big WordPress plugin which consist of a couple of classes and interfaces (*which use proper namespacing*). From research and what answers I got from previous questions, the best option was to use interface injection (*dependency injection*) to maintain SOC. Everything at this stage work as intended.

I'm left now with bringing everything together into one main class which will be used as a contoller. At this moment, to test everything, I use `require_once` in order to load my classes and interfaces (*files are in a folder called `functions`*)

### EXAMPLE:

```
require_once( '/functions/INTERFACEA.php' );
require_once( '/functions/CLASSA.php'     );
require_once( '/functions/INTERFACEB.php' );
require_once( '/functions/CLASSB.php'     );
//etc
```

I have heard about autoloaders, but does not completely understand how to use them in a controller class. One issue that I really need to avoid is that a class is loaded before its interface, because if the load sequence is wrong, I get a fatal error stating that my interface does not exist.

### MY QUESTION:

How do I properly make use of an autoloader in a controller class to load my classes and intefaces which also makes sure that my interfaces are loaded before their respective classes

Comment: If you use namespaces you can simply place stuff in the according folders `\Goosen\interfaces\InterfaceA`, `\Goosen\interfaces\InterfaceB`, `\Goosen\classes\ClassA` etc., and just place them at `lib/goosen/interfaces/InterfaceA.php`. In your autoloader you can then simply check if the currently class trying to be autoloaded is of the "Goosen" namespace, and then you'd know the path. "*which also makes sure that my interfaces are loaded before their respective classes*" this isn't nessesary - the autoloader will handle other classes too including dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) for autoloading your classes. It supports namespaces for autoloading and, once setup, everything would be simply automatic in their own namespaces.

All you have to do it to setup the composer.json

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"Acme\\": "src/"}
    }
```

Just require the aotoload.php and it will manage everything else.

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Will play around with this

Comment: Please. This is marvelous. You can use it's package manager feature too. Just one command and your project is setup anywhere. The autoloading  entries are little tricky when its mixed with name spaces. But you are just done once you get there.

Comment: Composer is great for anything in a dev environment, but it might not be such a great idea to depend on 3rd party libraries as a first plan. Of course, if you plan to distribute the 3rd party libs, fine, use composer. But you should use namespaces and spl_autoload_register first I think.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `spl_autoload_register`

```
// Defining autoloader
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {

    // just make sure here that $class_name is correct file name
    // and there is $class_name.php file if no the fix it 
    // E.G. use strtoupper etc.
    $class_name = strtoupper($class_name);

    require_once( '/functions/'.$class_name.'.php' );
});

// Then simply use 
$class = new CLASSA();
// if `CLASSA` implements `INTERFACEA` here php 
// will autoload `INTERFACEA.php` and `CLASSA.php`
```

Check this article for more info: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will play around with this